# BCNF decomposition that results in different decompositions (both faithful or faithless)?

Tags: database-normalization, bcnf

This is a question 19.10 (4) in the textbook Database management systems by Raghu Ramakrishnan, Johannes Gehrke (in case anyone's curious - answer not included of course, which is why I needed to ask)

And I noticed that there are two ways to make the BCNF decomposition:

We're given R = ABCD
and the functional Dependencies: A -> B, B -> C, C -> D

Key: A
We can decompose it to BCNF by either using B -> C or C -> D at the start

If decompose along B -> C at the start, get R1 = AB , R2 = BC , R3 = BD (this is not faithful)
If decompose along C ->D at the start, get R1 = AB, R2 = BC , R3 = CD  (this is faithful)

I'm quite new to the doing BCNF decomposition, is this correct? So it's possible to have multiple different BCNF decompositions depending on your chosen starting FD?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Right before you decompose it, what are you supposed to have? Just a list of FDs and a key? Find out.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.. we are just given the relation with four attributes ABCD and the list of FDs.
From the list of FDs I determined that the key is A, and then go on from there

Comment: What is your algorithm, exactly, from a reference?